# Error: sudo: amazon-linux-extras: command not found

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, ubuntu-20.04

**System Information:** `Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1045-aws x86_64)`

**Problem:** Trying to run `sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y` and `sudo yum install -y chromium` Because i need it for my Discord Bot which has the error of:

Discord Bot Error:

```
Mashwishi using command cyt!price
/home/container/node_modules/node-html-to-image/node_modules/puppeteer-cluster/dist/Cluster.js:120
                    throw new Error(`Unable to launch browser, error message: ${err.message}`);
                          ^

Error: Unable to launch browser, error message: Failed to launch the browser process!
/home/container/node_modules/node-html-to-image/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-737027/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libXcomposite.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

    at Cluster.<anonymous> (/home/container/node_modules/node-html-to-image/node_modules/puppeteer-cluster/dist/Cluster.js:120:27)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at rejected (/home/container/node_modules/node-html-to-image/node_modules/puppeteer-cluster/dist/Cluster.js:6:65)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

So I went to check the article for troubleshooting [Running Puppeteer on AWS EC2 instance running Amazon-Linux](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-on-aws-ec2-instance-running-amazon-linux) since we're running Amazon AWS EC2. So I tried to the commands:

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
```

**The error is:** `sudo: amazon-linux-extras: command not found`

```
sudo yum install -y chromium
```

**The error is:** `sudo: yum: command not found`

Comment: ```log
root@ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX:~# sudo apt install chromium
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package chromium is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  chromium-bsu
E: Package 'chromium' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: So all i need to do is to use `sudo apt install chromium` ? do i have to restart to apply and reflect the changes?

Comment: Reboot is usually required only with an update of libc6 (glibc) and kernel = e.g. https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/linux-aws . ........ Your first comment : Sorry, the Ubuntu package name is `chromium-browser` https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/chromium-browser

Comment: Successfully installed, Hoping that `puppeteer` will work without problem now..

Comment: Also tried installing `linux-headers-aws` and `linux-image-aws` says that it was already installed. not sure if its because of the `chromium-browser` or it is already installed.

Comment: Got new error now

Comment: ```log
(node:3563) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unable to launch browser, error message: Failed to launch the browser process!
/home/container/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-901912/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Seems AWS doesn't match the Ubuntu "snap chromium" (The apt chromium is a redirect to snap.) ..... Please use https://www.google.com/chrome/ → `google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to install Java on Machine --Amazon Linux 2023 AMI 2023,

and if the error you are getting is

> sudo: amazon-linux-extras: command not found

The command which helps install Java successfully here is

```
sudo dnf install java-11-amazon-corretto -y
```